# libquadmath.a is not installed but still found by gfortran

Tags: static-libraries, ld, gfortran, static-linking, lib

The man page of ld (which I think is used by gfortran in the background) says:

> -lnamespec: ...If namespec is of the form :filename, ld will search the library path
> for a file called filename...

Compiling the trivial Fortran program test.f:

```
       END
```

with `gfortran -l:libquadmath.a test.f` does not throw an error on some of my machines (CENTOS 7 with GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)).

However, `for f in $(echo $LIBRARY_PATH | sed 's/:/ /g');do find $f -name libquadmath.a; done` gives zero results, indicating that there is no file called libquadmath.a.

Additonally, the output of `ld -l:libquadmath.a` is `ld: cannot find -l:libquadmath.a`.

What is going on here?

Comment: Try rather `find / -name "libquadmath*"`. And check also `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`.

Comment: If libquadmath.a was installed with your version of gfortran, then you do not need to specify `-lquadmath` if gfortran is invoking the linker.  gfortran will automatically add it.

Comment: @steve can you clarify what you mean by "installed with your version of gfortran"? Does it mean that the library was hardcoded into the gfortran executable?

Comment: When GCC is built, it can be configure to use quad precision or not.  If it is built with quad precision support, then libquadmath.a is installed and available to gfortran.  gfortran knows how to find its  libraries.  Compile `real(16) :: x = 1 ; print *, atan(x) ; end`.  The program requires libquadmath for `atan(x)`.  Assume a.f90 is the file and do `gfortran -o z a.f90 |& grep quad`  if this returns nothing then GCC was not built with quad precision support.  Finally, do `gfortran --verbose` and look for `--disable-quadmath`

Comment: Thanks! You said "gfortran knows how to find its libraries". But what kind of magic does it use to achieve that? I still don't know if it includes a actual file that is somewhere stored on my disk or not...